# Kubernetes Galera: WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110:

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, centos7, galera

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes Galera 3 Replica set. I am using:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/test/e2e/testing-manifests/statefulset/mysql-galera

The first pod spins up fine, but the second pod gets stuck:

```
1 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
         at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():162
2018-07-21 18:24:40 1 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2018-07-21 18:24:40 1 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379: Failed to open channel 'mysql' at 'gcomm://mysql-0.galera.mysql.svc.cluster.local,mysql-1.galera.mysql.svc.cluster.local': -110 (Connection timed out)
2018-07-21 18:24:40 1 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
2018-07-21 18:24:40 1 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://mysql-0.galera.mysql.svc.cluster.local,mysql-1.galera.mysql.svc.cluster.local) failed: 7
2018-07-21 18:24:40 1 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Do I need to have etcd setup for this cluster to work? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Kubernetes Info:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:53:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:43:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: how many nodes do you have? Your statefulset (STS) manifest wants 3 replicas? Can you describe the status of your STS?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 nodes available.  I've tested it with 2 nodes as well but doesn't work either.  It creates the first pod fine and goes to running, but it seems that the second pod that is created can't connect to the first.